# passing output of a program (samtools) to another program (bamToBed) fails

Tags: bash, io-redirection

How should I pass output of one command to another program like this:

```
samtools view -bf 0x2 p1163.novo.tier2.bam | bamToBed -i stdin | coverageBed -a stdin -b genes.bed
```

But the stdin does not work in my terminal.

Comment: In what way does stdin not work?

Comment: well. It throws this error."Failed to open BAM file stdin"

Comment: That error probably means one of your programs is trying to open a file called stdin instead of using file descriptor 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bamToBed -i /dev/stdin
```

or

```
bamToBed -i -
```

should work. There was a bug.

Edit:
and `-b` as samtools option is crucial.

Comment: Hi. I still get error.     `$ samtools view -f 0x2 500bp_insert_mapping_subset2_sorted.bam | bamToBed -i /dev/stdin`
Failed to open BAM file /dev/stdin
`$ samtools view -f 0x2 500bp_insert_mapping_subset2_sorted.bam | bamToBed -i -`
Failed to open BAM file -

Comment: now you forgot `-b` in samtools to output BAM format...

Comment: cool. It works! I forgot to add "b", which was why it was throwing error. my bad. With "b" even stdin worked! Thank you very much!